# Seconds from minutes

Tags: c#, math

I need to figure out time in seconds but the only information I can receive is minutes.

So I can send a request to the server every 5 seconds and I'll get a response back basically saying "Hey you have 10 minutes left", after 5 seconds I can send another request to the server and it'll either say "Hey you still have 10 minutes left" or it'll say "Hey you've got 9 minutes left now."

I thought well I could start a timer once it tells me I have 9 minutes left.  But this isn't going to be accurate down to the second due to the fact I'm refreshing every 5 seconds and sometimes the server can take a little longer to send me the information then it did the last time I asked.

So my question basically is there any way I can accurately figure out how many seconds I have left based on the criteria above?

Edit: How often I send the request can be adjusted.

Comment: No, unless you just send requests more frequently.

Comment: Does your request have to be every 5 seconds?  5 goes into 60 too neatly to be of any use over time.

Comment: Sorry I made the edit just a moment ago, just realized I can adjust the request time.

Comment: The only thing you can do is some best-guess estimate of the amount of second, based on previous timing information.

Comment: You can start your timer at 9 minutes (±5 seconds), and when you think it hits each minute mark, ask.  You'll be able to adjust your bisect your uncertainty.  But I'm not sure what you mean how much longer the server can take to send the information.  Does the server always receive the information the same amount of time after it's been sent, and it's just how long it take you to get the response from the server that is variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you watch a clock tick over from 11:43 to 11:44, don't you know roughly what the seconds count is? If as soon as it ticks over to 44 you start a stopwatch, now you can compute what the seconds are from the stopwatch.

If you can query every x seconds, you can know how many seconds are left with an error of roughly x seconds. You need a high-resolution/high-accuracy time source locally, such as the high performance counter in windows, available via the `Stopwatch` class or by pinvokes `GetPerformanceCounter` and `GetPerformanceFrequency`.

So you have the following parts:

- A local clock with high resolution and accurracy. The HPET via `GetPerformanceCounter` qualifies, and you might be able to use the `Stopwatch` class to access it without writing any pinvokes (but I wrote my own wrapper instead of using `Stopwatch`).
- A remote clock that you're trying to improve on the accuracy of.
- The ability to query the remote clock.

The general strategy is as follows:

- Query your local high-accuracy counter. Save this as 'L1'.
- Query the remote clock. Save this as 'R1'.
- Query the remote clock. Save this as 'R2'.
- Query your local high-accuracy counter. Save this as 'L2'.

You need to do the above in a loop (and when you do, you can optimize it further).

If your remote clock only ever tells you minutes, then almost every time you query it, R1 and R2 are exactly the same value.

However, if you happened to catch it right as it ticked over to the next minute, R1 and R2 should differ by exactly one minute. If that happened, then the local counters L1 and L2 tell you exactly how much time passed during that entire loop.

If L2 - L1 tells you that only 100 milliseconds passed, then you know that time 'R2 and zero seconds' occurred somewhere in that 100 milliseconds.

So when you're performing the above loop:

- R1 and R2 tell you what the remote time is, and tell you if you saw it tick over to the next minute - the 'zero seconds' time.
- L1 and L2 tell you what the corresponding local time is to that 'zero seconds' time, and they tell you how much error you have.

Once you have a set of timestamps to work with, you can compute the remote time from just your local high accuracy clock.

Local time `(R2 - R1) / 2` (call that value LocalMark) roughly equals "R2 and zero seconds" (call that value RemoteMark).

From there, the remote time computed from the local time is computed as follows:

```
RemoteTime = (LocalTime - LocalMark) + RemoteMark
```

`LocalTime - LocalMark` tells you how much time has passed since `RemoteMark` was taken, so if you add those two parts together, you should have the remote time.

...

The above is my take on what I learned from an MSDN article I found some number of years ago. Unfortunately, Microsoft has retired that article, and it can only be found by the wayback machine:

[Implement a Continuously Updating, High-Resolution Time Provider for Windows](http://web.archive.org/web/20130724074742/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163996.aspx).

You can also recover the article from the [MSDN archives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee310108.aspx) - it was in the March 2004 issue of MSDN magazine, available as a CHM - [March 2004 CHM with the article](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/a/7/3a7fa450-1f33-41f7-9e6d-3aa95b5a6aea/MSDNMagazineMarch2004en-us.chm)

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is relaxation on the offset error:
each time you seem to be in advance or late, let loc_error be the estimate ( possibly just +1/-1 if you don't have better).
Then let time_offset be 0.99*time_offset + 0.1*loc_error, depending of how "noisy" is the local error information and how fast you want to converge toward the right value.